# JFrog returning No Violation Found

Tags: jfrog-xray

Good Morning all,
Anyone using JFrog here?
I need some basic guidance on how to scan a repository with Xray. It's currently returning zero violations but I'm not sure if it is even scanning at all

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below points and make sure you have configured it in Xray.

1. Xray DB sync is up to date. Link for more details-> https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+Xray#ConfiguringXray-SynchronizingtheDatabase
2. Indexing of repositories/builds is enabled. Link for more details-> https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+Xray#ConfiguringXray-IndexingResources
3. Watches and policies are created and configured to the Artifactory repository or build. Link for more details-> https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+Xray#ConfiguringXray-CreatingWatchesandPolicies

Below are the video link to create Watches and policies.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfoBmuaRkGI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88hwwMJsS58

I  hope the above information will be helpful to configure Xray for the repository or build and check for violations.